# Can't run my c# project on a diffrent pc

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I have made a C#-project which runs operations on a database for that I have used Entity Framework, the program was running well on my pc. Then I made an installation file, after installing it on another pc when I launch the software it start normally but the moment I try to read/write from the database it stops "software has stopped working".
why is that ?

Comment: did you change the ConnectionString?

Comment: Without more information, its impossible to answer your question.  You need to add some logging and error handling to your code.  The "stopped working" issue usually means some top level call threw an exception.

Comment: Khaled, this question is going to attract sarcasm and downvotes en masse. You need to add more detail if you want anyone to be able to help. As it stands, there's a (figuratively) infinite list of possible causes, and no way for anyone except you to investigate.

Comment: when I debug it is says "no installed debugger has just-in-time debugging enabled"

Comment: Try looking in the Windows Event Viewer on the machine with the error.  Sometimes that can reveal some detail about the error.  But as stated earlier, you will likely need to add exception handling to your code using `try catch` statements and then log when exceptions are caught.

Comment: People are too quick to downvote / close these kinds of questions, for beginners looking at problems, they often think there is one answer to their question, for an experienced person, they see many possibilities, it is better to ask for more information in the comments than downvote / close.     https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/

Comment: @KeithNicholas I'm not seeing much snark in these comments (with the exception of itsme's); while I can appreciate your sentiment I don't see how a specific answer (yours gives general debugging advice) can be written yet. That's more or less what the closure system is made for.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET  because you used the word "yet" to me that isn't target for closure, that's a target for getting more info so it can be answered.  Target for clousure is when, even with more information, the question can't be answered within the bounds of questions SO is designed for.

Comment: @KeithNicholas We can agree to disagree but the very first line of the help center for closure says: "Questions that need additional work" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is not direct as it doesn't point directly to one answer, however the most likely cause is that the installed app can't see the database.  Either you aren't distributing the database with your application, or if it is meant to connect to a central database, then the connection string isn't correct, or it can't see it via the network.

The second thing when you get errors like this is to ask yourself why you don't know what the problem is.

1) add logging to your application, use a standard logging system like log4net ( or any other standard one )

2) handle errors properly, if something can fail, check the result and let the user know and log it.  Anything that accesses files or crosses process boundaries ( like databases ) can fail in normal operation, so the code always need to be designed to be robust if things don't work AND to give you as much information as possible so you can resolve the error